# How to display data from a SQL Server database on an ASP.NET web page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

So, here's my SQL query:

```
      SELECT [Gender], count(*)
      FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUser]
      WHERE Gender='M'
      GROUP BY Gender
```

In SMSS, this returns

```
      M 5298
```

I want to print out that value (5298) in a div or a header on my webpage.

So, in my Index.cshtml I tried

```
      @using WebMatrix.Data;
      @{
      var db = Database.Open("usersdbconnectionstring"); 
      var selectQueryString = "SELECT [Gender], count(*) FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUser] WHERE Gender='M' GROUP BY Gender"; 
      }
```

I ripped that off from an example on W3C schools and it worked for printing out a table but not for this.

This didn't work either:

```
      @WebMatrix.Data
      @{
      var db = Database.Open("usersdbconnectionstring");
      var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT [Gender], count(*) FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUser] WHERE Gender='M' GROUP BY Gender");
      var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
       }
       <div>
       @grid.GetHtml()
       </div>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: What is meant by *not working*. are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0):

In `MVC` pattern, you should not implement SQL query in views. If you are working with `Entity Framework`, you can do it like this:

**Model:**
add `edmx` to project (See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)).

**Controller:** 
In your `action` get data from db and pass to `View` (See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)).

**View:** 
Show data model in View (See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)).